# How to remove an error text below my textfield in Flutter

Tags: flutter, textfield

I am using a TextField widget in my Flutter app, and I want to change the border color based on some condition. I am using the borderSide property of the OutlineInputBorder to set the border color, and it seems to work for displaying an error message when the condition is met. However, even when the condition is not met, the border color remains red.

```
 TextField(
  controller: userName,
  onChanged: (value) {},
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: "Email",
    errorText: valid == true ? "" : "Not Good",
    errorStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: valid == true ? 0 : 12),
    prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.email),
    border: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: valid == true ? Colors.black : Colors.red,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use errorBorder:

```
TextField(
  onChanged: (value) {},
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    errorBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 0.0),
    ),
    hintText: "Email",
    errorText: valid == true ? "email" : "Not Good",
    errorStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: valid == true ? 0 : 12),
    prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.email),
    border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        borderSide:
            BorderSide(color: valid == true ? Colors.black : Colors.blue)),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a parameter called `errorBorder` in `InputDecoration()`. You can use it to add a custom border on error.

```dart
TextField(
 decoration: InputDecoration(
            errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(),),
)
```